# Spring Boot didn't connect to my database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I connected my Postgres database with Spring Boot but something when wrong. I didn't show any error but it didn't go into the database.
*I have replace my Postgres URL with $URl and $password for security issue.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://$URL:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=$password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and  the result was only these

```
2021-12-08 17:31:03.430  INFO 4216 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.1 on DESKTOP with PID 4006 (C:\Users\Thanh Lu\Desktop\demo\target\classes started by Thanh Lu in C:\Users\Any\Desktop\demo)
2021-12-08 17:31:03.431  INFO 4216 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-08 17:31:03.655  INFO 4216 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.378 seconds (JVM running for 0.634)
```

and my Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any advice would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't find JPA/Hibernate dependency in your Maven pom.xml. Try to add the following dependency there:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not used any object or config relate to database.
Simple, you can try create entity then add following 2 configuration in file application.properties

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

And in your Maven pom.xml add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then start project again you can see result as image below
[image]